# Finding a relation which is transitive and its reverse is not

Tags: math

I have the following task:

Find a non-empty relation `R`, which is transitive and `R^-1` is not transitive

`R^-1` meaning reverse relation.
For example for `R={1->2,2->3}`  `R^-1={2->1, 3->2}`

I tried to get to it myself but I can't. I've even written a loop, that creates random relations and checks if they fulfill these criteria. So far I found nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Agreed. This is not a homework solutions site, in any case.

Comment: nothing to do with mathematica either

Answer (score 1):

No such relation exists. Suppose `R` is a transitive relation and take any elements like `b->a` and `c->b` of `R^-1`.  Then `a->b` and `b->c` are elements of `R`, and since `R` is transitive `a->c` is in `R`. So `c->a` is in `R^-1`, which is exactly what we needed for `R^-1` to be transitive.

If you wanna be silly, you could view `R` as a category, where the morphisms are the given by the relations, and we have that all the necessary morphism compositions exist because of the transitivity of the relation. In this context, what we've proven above is that if you take all the morphisms in `R` and turn them around, the thing we get is also a category, which is commonly called `R^op`, the *opposite* category to `R`.